# html table overflow hidden only for a td

Tags: html, css, html-table, overflow

What we know is the width total of the table and the first column. The 3 and 4 column must adapt to the content, and the second column must use the rest of space. This second column must set the overflow hidden, allowing only one line or a line 
 line

Maybe the fiddle is more clear

http://jsfiddle.net/favio41/9z867/

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col class="col1" />
        <col class="col2" />
        <col class="col3" />
        <col class="col4" />
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="date">
                <span class="month monthAndYear">Feb</span>
                <br/>
                <span class="day ng-binding">21</span>
            </td>
            <td style="background-image: url(resources/img/categories/G0400.png);" class="category_icon cat_G0400">
                <span class="concepto ng-binding">This is a example of text</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span data-tooltip="Internet, teléfono fijo" class="cat-label cat-tooltip onlyTitle">
                    <span class="text ng-binding">Internet</span>
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class="importe">
                <span class="importe_value ng-binding">-33,23</span>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="date">
                <span class="month monthAndYear">Feb</span>
                <br />
                <span class="day ng-binding">21</span>
            </td>
            <td style="background-image: url(resources/img/categories/G0400.png);" class="category_icon cat_G0400">
                <span class="concepto ng-binding">This is a example of text, but this is really big and we want to be hidden the last part because if is too big ...</span>
                <br/>
                <span class="descripcion ng-binding">This is a example of description text</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span data-tooltip="Internet, teléfono fijo" class="cat-label cat-tooltip onlyTitle">
                    <span class="text ng-binding">Internet</span>
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class="importe">
                <span class="importe_value ng-binding">-33,23</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a DIV in the cell you want to have overflow. Set the dimensions and overflow for the DIV, not the TD.

Comment: This is a GREAT idea, but this way, I am forced to put a width in the div, but do not work in percentage. fiddle with the change: http://jsfiddle.net/favio41/f5sJt/

Comment: I'm not sure what you want the result to be, but you can limit the width of the TD and leave the DIV without a width declaration (defaults to 100%) .cat_G0400  {max-width:300px}